# flexslider 2 ul with "slide" class doesn't show up with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

I'm trying to use Flexslider 2 with bootstrap 3 .The problem is after I place flexslider 2 codes and run the page , The UL with "slide" class is out of the page .

Have a look at the following pictures and you will know the problem .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mOWv.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/83koX.jpg

I don't know If it has conflict with bootstrap 3 .How should I fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both the images look exactly the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please read this -> **http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask** and this -> **http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**. 
Think about it : **1**) how should anyone be able to answer a programming problem causing a certain unexpected behaviour without a single line of code? **2**) even if you get lucky, it wont help anyone else in the future.